# #1824 - Failed to open the referenced table 'ders'

Tags: mysql

Hello guys i was trying to make a foreign key of ders_id in the table ogrenciler but it's giving me this error in mysql

#1824 - Failed to open the referenced table 'ders'

ders table is already exists and there's no problem in it

and this was my code

```
CREATE TABLE ogrenciler (
    id INT,
    ders_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (ders_id)
        REFERENCES ders(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind removing the php tag since this is about mysql tables. Thank you.

Comment: Post the SQL for the `ders` table. Is `id` a primary key on it?

Comment: yes id is a primary key on ders table

Comment: mysql is always right, maybe you are connected to the wrong database or you have somewhere a typo or a character that doesn't show, but it would show if you `show CREATE tABLE `ders`

Comment: i'm sure that i'm typing the name of the reference table right

Comment: Is `ders` in a different schema? Or is `ders` not using the InnoDB storage engine?